# How to determine whether AVM1Movie is finished?

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm using Loader to add AMV1Movie (movie created using [Toon Boom Studio](http://www.toonboom.com/products/toon-boom-studio/)) to my AS3.0 stage. How can I determine when AMV1Movie plays it's last frame?

Comment: Do you have access to the AVM1Movie's source ? If so, you could use LocalConnection to establish communication between the as2 and as3 movies, so the as2 movie can tell the as3 movie that it's finished playing.

Comment: I'm not sure if there's some way to write code in this ToonBoom-stuff. But I'll try. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Without dispatching something from the original movie, you'd have to poll it's currentFrame and numFrames properties, and that will only be accurate if the main timeline is an accurate depiction of the animation/program. If the AVM1Movie animates via code or has nested movieclips, there's no good way to know when it is "finished".

The best bet is to open it up and add an event to the end.

Comment: There is no currentFrame and numFrames in AVM1Movie public interface

Answer (score 0):

I use ForcibleLoader to load AVM1Movie as MovieClip:

```
var uic: UIComponent = ....
 ...
var loader:Loader = Loader(1uic.addChild(new Loader()));
loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, startPlay);
var fLoader:ForcibleLoader = new ForcibleLoader(loader);
fLoader.load(new URLRequest("....swf"));
```

then I check if (movie.currentFrame + 1 >= movie.totalFrames)

I use this function to control uic.click event to stop and play movie:

```
private function controlSwf(event: Event): void {
    var e: Event = event;
    var movie: MovieClip = MovieClip(Loader(event.target).content);
    if (movie.currentFrame + 1 >= movie.totalFrames) {
        movie.gotoAndPlay(1);
        play = true;
    } else if (play) {
        play = false;
        movie.stop();
    } else {
        play = true;
        movie.play();

    }
}
```